# integrate a third party component

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `react-infinity` as an example here. ([Link to `react-infinity`'s Readme](https://github.com/nmn/react-infinity))

After doing `var Infinity = require('react-infinity')`, you have access to an `Infinity` variable with various `props`.

(I presume `Infinity` is going to be used inside some component I create, e.g. `myComponent`)

This is where I am stumped. How am I supposed to use this `Infinity` variable?

Answer (score 1):

you would use it as just another JSX component as follows...

```
//.....
render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Infinity {...props} />
      </div>
    );
}
//.....
```

where `props` are whatever properties the thirdparty component specs.

Comment: Did this answer your question?